# How can I find all PHP files with group write permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I've been trying to get the `-perm` option of `find` to give me all PHP files that are group writable. Should this work?

```
find -name "*.php" -perm g-w
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
find -iname "*.php" -perm -g=w
```

`-g=w` means look for files that have this permission set.

Comment: May want `-iname` just in case some are .PHP for some bizzare reason.

Comment: @daenyth - Good point! Added it to my answer! +1

Comment: @kristopher - You're very welcome!