# How do I find all files that are *not* group writeable?

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I see the following question describing how to find group writeable files:
[How can I find all PHP files with group write permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/155885/how-can-i-find-all-php-files-with-group-write-permissions)

But I want files that are *not* group writable! (Also, I couldn't comment on the above question).

Google lets me down (as 'find' isn't such a unique keyword).

Comment: Which OS is this for?

Comment: I updated the tag based on the linked question. Please change if not correct.

Comment: You can't comment on other people's posts until you have 50 rep, which is why you couldn't comment there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming that the linked question would run on your system, you can invert the match with `!`:

```
find ! -perm -g=w
```

Also, you can read the documentation for `find` by looking into the manpages:

```
man find
```

Comment: The full command to start searching within current directory would be
`find . ! -perm -g=w`

Answer (score 6):

On BSD derived Unix system (macOS, FreeBSD, ...) you need to add a path to `find`. So for a more compatible version add `.` to search in the current directory and `!` to invert the match:

```
find . ! -perm -g=w
```